# important field of gridelements empty (tx_gridelements_view_columns)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i installed gridelements 9.4.2 in a TYPO3 9.5.24. In the backend all works as expected but in the frontend i did not get the child elements of a grid container.

When testing with <f:debug>{_all} i can see that tx_gridelements_backend_layout contains my correct grid layout and tx_gridelements_children shows me the correct number of children in the grid container.

But tx_gridelements_view_columns is an empty array and tx_gridelements_view_column_0 is missing completely; there is only a tx_gridelements_view_column_ without the correct number.

tx_gridelements_view_children is missing also.

Any idea what is wrong? Why does gridelements not collect the content elements in the container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the new way from gridelements here: `/gridelements/Resources/Private/`

The new Way like `DataProcessing` with the `f:for each`